Why is my Laravel 11 exception handler not working?
Using Laravel 11, exception handling is moved to the bootstrap/app.php file. I'm trying to catch AuthorizationException and pass the user back to the dashboard with the 403 message:
// bootstrap/app.php

use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ...
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        $exceptions->render(function (AuthorizationException $e, Request $request) {
            return redirect()
                ->route('dashboard')
                ->withErrors($e->getMessage());
        });
        ...
    })
    ...
    ->create();

But it's not working. This logged in user is gated from seeing the /users endpoint, but it's not being handled by my exception handler. They should be seeing their dashboard. (My .env does show APP_DEBUG=true.)

(Using barryvdh/laravel-debugbar in this screenshot)

rather than coming up with hacky solutions, it would be better to ask this to the maintainers, as this is likely something related to Laravel 11

@krisgjika this is so true. I've had this problem when I upgraded from 10 to 11, and the bootstrap\app.php has changed

Update (thanks @Olivier):
Laracasts forum answered this wonderfully: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-catch-a-policy-response-exception

My Original:
Changed exception type-hint to just Throwable to inspect whatever gets caught:
$exceptions->render(function (Throwable $e, Request $request) {
    dd($e);
    ...
});

...and it looks like it skipped the AuthorizationException and passed a Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException

Question now is "why?" Why do Laravel docs not give more detail about how to handle common exceptions? Anyways, it's solved, but others might have the same issue, so here's my fix:
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;

return Application
    ::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ...
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        $exceptions->render(function (Throwable $e) {
            if ( $e instanceof AccessDeniedHttpException ) {
                /* This may be overly specific, but I want to handle other
                   potential AccessDeniedHttpExceptions when I come
                   across them */
                if ( $e->getPrevious() instanceof AuthorizationException ) {
                    return redirect()
                        ->route('dashboard')
                        ->withErrors($e->getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    })
    ->create();


The exception is not skipped, it's wrapped. See here for more details.
